# A product of distinct prime numbers cannot be a square minus one

Tags: number-theory

> If $2=P_1<P_2<\dots<P_n$ where $P_i$ are primes.  Show that the number $P_1P_2P_3\cdots P_n +1$ can never be a perfect square.

I always have problem with these kind of questions. How do I get comfortable with Number Theory? How do you approach a problem?

Comment: $$3+1=?, 3\cdot5+1=?$$

Comment: I think you must mean "show that $p_1p_2\cdots p_n+1$ can not be a perfect square" where $p_i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ prime.

Answer (score 1):

$X = P_1P_2P_3\cdots P_n +1$

X-1 is even, so X is odd

$X = a \times a$

a has to be odd

$Y = X - 1 = a^2 - 1 = (a - 1)(a + 1)$

(a - 1) and (a + 1) are evens

Y cannot be the product of two even numbers, otherwise it would have to have the prime 2 as a factor more than once, so the uniqueness of prime decomposition shows that the conditions cannot be met

Comment: _Good, good..._